# Python-Requests close http connection

Tags: python, http, urllib2, httplib, python-requests

I was wondering, how do you close a connection with Requests (python-requests.org)?

With `httplib` it's `HTTPConnection.close()`, but how do I do the same with Requests?

Code:

```
r = requests.post("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json", data={'track':toTrack}, auth=('username', 'passwd'))
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        self.mongo['db'].tweets.insert(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: I don't think Requests establishes a persistent connection... there's no connection to close.

Comment: @michael, you get a persistent connection pool for free unless you specify otherwise http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive

Comment: @istruble Then urllib3 handles cleaning up the connection pool?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272653/in-what-conditions-are-closing-a-http-connection-necessary/3272700#3272700), there really isn't such a thing as an HTTP connection and what httplib refers to as the HTTPConnection is really the underlying TCP connection which doesn't really know much about your requests at all. Requests abstracts that away and you won't ever see it.

The newest version of Requests does in fact keep the TCP connection alive after your request.. If you do want your TCP connections to close, you can just configure the requests to not use [keep-alive](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive).

```
s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
```

Comment: Alternatively `s = requests.session(config={'keep_alive': False})`

Comment: OP was asking how to close a streaming response.  I don't see how setting keep-alive on the session is going to help there.  There are several recent tickets in requests and urllib3 around this issue: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/132, https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1073, https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1041

Comment: See comment here: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/132#issuecomment-11516729

Comment: Current `request` versions have *no support* for switching off Keep-Alive.

Comment: As of the current release you can ensure streaming connections go back to the pool by reading Response.content (or Response.text which calls Response.content). But if you are hoarding Response objects without reading them you will not be releasing your connections back: [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive)

Comment: TypeError: session() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'

Answer (score 80):

I think a more reliable way of closing a connection is to tell the sever explicitly to close it in a way [compliant with HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to
>   signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
>   response. For example,
>
> ```
>    Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the
>   connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after
>   the current request/response is complete.

The `Connection: close` header is added to the actual request:

```
r = requests.post(url=url, data=body, headers={'Connection':'close'})
```

Comment: What is 'body' in this case? just any { }?

Comment: @Brad It depends on content-type, e.g. if you want to send application/json, you can use data=json.dumps(payload), if you just want to send a common form-encoded payload, you can use data={"k1":"v1", ...}. See more details here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: That's being used [here](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/blob/master/pycorenlp/corenlp.py#L29) but for some reason it appears that the connection is not really closed - I notices because my OS runs out of ports - which should not happen imho if that connection gets closed correctly. :/

Comment: This helped me with `Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

Answer (score 75):

I came to this question looking to solve the `"too many open files" error`, but I am using `requests.session()` in my code. A few searches later and I came up with an answer on the [Python Requests Documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) which suggests to use the `with` block so that the session is closed even if there are unhandled exceptions:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('http://google.com')
```

If you're not using Session you can actually do the same thing: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

```
with requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', stream=True) as r:
    # Do something
```

Comment: Am I supposed to downvote other comments in order to help this one to go up?

Comment: @dmigo:  No.  Only downvote if an answer is wrong in some way, or otherwise not useful to the question asked.

Comment: Lets say i create a session using "with" in one function and return the session. Use the session in all my tests. How would i know if the session is terminated?

Comment: @manojprashantk The best answer I can give is to test it in your code. Likely the request will be closed once you're out of the `with` block but you should read about Context Managers as it may have more of an answer to your question: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers

Comment: Are you sure this works? requests.get() behind the scenes also uses the same construct, and the keep-alive is still working ...

Answer (score 28):

please use `response.close()` to close to avoid "too many open files" error

for example:

```
r = requests.post("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json", data={'track':toTrack}, auth=('username', 'passwd'))
....
r.close()
```

Comment: I was looking for answers for exactly this problem!

Comment: What is the max. number of connections can a session handle before giving error "too many open files"

Answer (score 12):

On Requests 1.X, the connection is available on the response object:

```
r = requests.post("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json",
                  data={'track': toTrack}, auth=('username', 'passwd'))

r.connection.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the latest requests(2.25.1), the `requests.<method>` will close the connection by default

```
with sessions.Session() as session:
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
```

https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L60

Thus, if you use the latest version of requests, it seems we don't need to close the connection by ourselves.

Also, if you need to send multiple times of requests with the same session, it's better to use `requests.Session()` instead of open/close the connection multiple times.
EX:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://example.org/1/')
    print(r.text)
    r = s.get('https://example.org/2/')
    print(r.text)
    r = s.get('https://example.org/3/')
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
res = requests.get(<url>, timeout=10).content
requests.session().close()
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the "keep-alive" header in requests, I just created it from the Request object and then send it with Session

```
headers = {
'Host' : '1.2.3.4',
'User-Agent' : 'Test client (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 7.16.3)',
'Accept' : '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding' : 'deflate, gzip',
'Accept-Language' : 'it_IT'
}

url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"
#r = requests.get(url, headers = headers) #this triggers keep-alive: True
s = requests.Session()
r = requests.Request('GET', url, headers)
```