# Repeated POST request is causing error "socket.error: (99, 'Cannot assign requested address')"

Tags: python, network-programming

I have a web-service deployed in my box. I want to check the result of this service with various input. Here is the code I am using:

```
import sys
import httplib
import urllib

apUrl = "someUrl:somePort"

fileName = sys.argv[1]
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(apUrl)

titlesFile = open(fileName, 'r')

try:
    for title in titlesFile:

        title = title.strip()
        params = urllib.urlencode({'search': 'abcd', 'text': title})
        conn.request("POST", "/somePath/", params)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read().strip()
        print data+"\t"+title

        conn.close()

finally:
    titlesFile.close()
```

This code is giving an error after same number of lines printed (28233). Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testService.py", line 19, in ?
    conn.request("POST", "/somePath/", params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 810, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 833, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 804, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 685, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 652, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 636, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: (99, 'Cannot assign requested address')
```

I am using Python 2.4.3. I am doing `conn.close()` also. But why is this error being given?

Comment: I googled for 28233 with error code and found this: http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=5995

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a python problem.

In linux kernel 2.4 the ephemeral port range is from 32768 through 61000. So number of available ports = 61000-32768+1 = 28233. From what i understood, because the web-service in question is quite fast (<5ms actually) thus all the ports get used up. The program has to wait for about a minute or two for the ports to close.

What I did was to count the number of `conn.close()`. When the number was 28000 wait for 90sec and reset the counter.

Answer (score 6):

BIGYaN identified the problem correctly and you can verify that by calling "netstat -tn" right after the exception occurs. You will see very many connections with state "TIME_WAIT".

The alternative to waiting for port numbers to become available again is to simply use one connection for all requests. You are not required to call `conn.close()` after each call of `conn.request()`. You can simply leave the connection open until you are done with your requests.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar issue while executing multiple POST statements using python's request library in Spark. To make it worse, I used multiprocessing over each executor to post to a server. So thousands of connections created in seconds that took few seconds each to change the state from TIME_WAIT and release the ports for the next set of connections.

Out of all the available solutions available over the internet that speak of disabling keep-alive, using with request.Session() et al, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511852/7103409) answer to be working which makes use of **'Connection' : 'close'** configuration as header parameter. You may need to put the header content in a separte line outside the post command though.

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'close'
}
with requests.Session() as session:
response = session.post('https://xx.xxx.xxx.x/xxxxxx/x', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
results = response.json()
print results
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735617/7103409) is my answer to the similar issue using the above solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19379689)

Comment: Got it Jonathan. Changed the answer accordingly. Thanks for the input.