# requests, cannot assign requested address, out of ports?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(99, 'Cannot assign requested address'))
```

I was getting this error when running multiple processes utilizing the python requests library and calling the `post` function to an API that was returning very quickly (<10ms).

Dialing down the number of processes running had a delaying effect, but only dialing down to 1 process eliminated the problem. This was not a solution, but did indicate a finite resource was the culprit.

Comment: Opening an outbound TCP connection randomly assigns a random port number in a high range (IIRC, the maximum is ~64k; where the range starts, vs ports reserved for inbound use, is configurable). Thus, if you have a really large number of outbound TCP connections open at the same time, no matter what library/programming language/etc. you're using, you're prone to hitting this issue.

Comment: This answer notes the available port range is 32768 through 61000. So number of available ports = 61000-32768+1 = 28233

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11208991/1942007

Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way I resolved my issue was to use the `requests.Session` class where I would reuse the same connection/session for each call in a given process.

Contrived example:

```
import requests
for line in file:
  requests.get('http://example.com/api?key={key}'.format(key=line['key']))
```

becomes

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
  for line in file:
    session.get('http://example.com/api?key={key}'.format(key=line['key']))
```

These questions had some related advice:

[Repeated POST request is causing error "socket.error: (99, 'Cannot assign requested address')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190595/repeated-post-request-is-causing-error-socket-error-99-cannot-assign-reques?rq=1)
[Python urllib2: Cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981933/python-urllib2-cannot-assign-requested-address?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I too faced similar issue while executing multiple POST statements using python's request library in Spark.
To make it worse, I used multiprocessing over each executor to post to a server.
So thousands of connections created in seconds that took few seconds each to change the state from TIME_WAIT and release the ports for the next set of connections.

Out of all the available solutions over the internet that speak of disabling keep-alive, using with request.Session() et al., I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511852/7103409) answer to be working. You may need to put the header content in a separate line outside the post command though.

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'close'
}
with requests.Session() as session:
response = session.post('https://xx.xxx.xxx.x/xxxxxx/x', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
results = response.json()
print results
```