# Python-Requests (>= 1.*): How to disable keep-alive?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm trying to program a simple web-crawler using the Requests module, and I would like to know how to disable its -default- keep-alive feauture.

I tried using:

```
s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
```

However, I get an error stating that session object has no attribute 'config', I think it was changed with the new version, but i cannot seem to find how to do it in the official documentation.

The truth is when I run the crawler on a specific website, it only gets five pages at most, and then keeps looping around infinitely, so I thought it has something to do with the keep-alive feature!

PS: is Requests a good module for a web-crawler? is there something more adapted?

Thank you !

Comment: This was [changed in 1.x](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#migrating-to-1-x)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works

```
s = requests.session()
s.keep_alive = False
```

[Answered in the comments of a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115126/python-requests-close-http-connection#comment22579942_10115553)

Comment: As far as a web crawler recommendation - SO should not be used for opinion based questions and answers. If you're interested in interacting with the web and web content, I would recommend doing some research on packages like scrapy, and beautifulsoup.

Comment: at least on current requests version it doesn't work - requests stll sends keep-alive header

Comment: doesnt work. requests:2.21.0. AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'keep_alive'

Comment: If you are hitting the AttributeError you can set headers on the session instead, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77564636/3407256

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure but can you try passing {"Connection": "close"} as HTTP headers when sending a GET request using requests. This will close the connection as soon a server returns a response.

```
>>> headers = {"Connection": "close"}
>>> r = requests.get('https://example.xcom', headers=headers)
```

Comment: I tried this, but aren't you supposed to use a POST request for that ? anyway the problem still persists !

Answer (score 5):

As @praveen suggested it's expected from us to use `HTTP/1.1` header  `Connection: close` to notify the server that the connection should be closed after completion of the response.

Here is how it's described in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that  the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example,
>
> ```
> Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is complete.
>
> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST include the "close" connection option in every message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hitting `AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'keep_alive'` then you are probably not using version 1, instead you can update the session headers like so:

```py
session.headers["Connection"] = "close"
```

You can see an example here: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5646