# Turning off keep-alive

Tags: python, python-requests, keep-alive, urllib3

In older versions of Requests there was option to turn off keep alive. Something like this:

```
s = requests.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
```

I also find in other question that I can use header Connection: close

```
HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal 
that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. 
For example,
   Connection: close
in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the 
connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after the 
current request/response is complete.
HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST 
include the "close" connection option in every message.
```

If I understand this properly it doesn't mean that connection will be closed. It's only information that it shouldn't be considered as persistent one.

How to do it in recent versions?

Comment: [Python-Requests (>= 1.*): How to disable keep-alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008953/python-requests-1-how-to-disable-keep-alive)

Comment: I`am also referring in my question to that. But my understanding of 'connection: close' header is different. That's why I had posted this question.