# Connection not persistent in python-requests

Tags: python, wireshark, python-requests

I am making a streaming POST request with around 12MB of body data. Once this request is complete, I intend to send another POST request on the same TCP connection. However, I do not see it happening on the same TCP connection. It takes place on an another TCP connection(as per Wireshark). As per my understanding from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115126/python-requests-close-http-connection&ei=YgHwUqntIZfpoATnn4GQDw&usg=AFQjCNE0khxIfsQ4FEqVqxvm3ajS47tg1Q&sig2=BrhvHPCMpJe4eBhZlYdeww&bvm=bv.60444564,d.cGU) and [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive), that should not be the case. Here is the snippet:

```
# First POST request without Auth info
with open(file) as f:
    r = requests.post(url, data=f, headers=h)

# Second POST request with Auth info
r = requests.post(url, headers=h)
```

I then tried using a [session object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), however, in this case I am not seeing the second POST request on the Wireshark (as a second POST method). It is actually getting appended in the end of the first streaming POST data:

```
# First POST request without Auth info
s = requests.session()
with open(file) as f:
    r = s.post(url, data=f, headers=h)

# Second POST request with Auth info
r = s.post(url, headers=h)
```

> SPBWZKSCM3RJQAKKC0B7UQ1DIRDWHPBXDYMTUPODQ4TFAFPZTQFMY6Q2SIY6ZET8W6BD4889Z69WMO7UIKQOZB22BOBQ1TH2EUUOOSQJA8B0Y***POST / HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Length:***

So, I have following questions:

1. why the first case does not work?
2. in the second case, why POST is getting appended to the previous streaming POST?

Thanks.