# Python requests module Error - cant load any url: 'Remote end closed connection without response'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, anaconda

I am trying to fetch data from an url using python 3.5 using the following code

```
import requests
url ='http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/einfo.fcgi'
r = requests.get(url)
r.content
```

The url can be opened with no problems in the browser.

However, I am getting an error (for this URL and any other URL I try) as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, **httplib_request_kw)
     375             try:  # Python 2.7, use buffering of HTTP responses
 --> 376                 httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
     377             except TypeError:  # Python 2.6 and older

 TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
 in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
     558                                                  timeout=timeout_obj,
 --> 559                                                   body=body, headers=headers)
     560 

 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
 in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout,
 **httplib_request_kw)
     377             except TypeError:  # Python 2.6 and older
 --> 378                 httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
     379         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

 C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)    1173          
 try:
 -> 1174                 response.begin()    1175             except ConnectionError:

 C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
     281         while True:
 --> 282             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
     283             if status != CONTINUE:
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
>     250             # sending a valid response.
> --> 251             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
>     252                                      " response")
> 
> RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last) C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in
> send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>     369                     retries=self.max_retries,
> --> 370                     timeout=timeout
>     371                 )
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
> in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
> assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
>     608             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
> --> 609                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>     610             retries.sleep()
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py
> in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
>     244             if read is False:
> --> 245                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
>     246             elif read is not None:
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py
> in reraise(tp, value, tb)
>     308         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
> --> 309             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>     310         raise value
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
> in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
> assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
>     558                                                   timeout=timeout_obj,
> --> 559                                                   body=body, headers=headers)
>     560 
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
> in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout,
> **httplib_request_kw)
>     377             except TypeError:  # Python 2.6 and older
> --> 378                 httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
>     379         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)    1173          
> try:
> -> 1174                 response.begin()    1175             except ConnectionError:
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
>     281         while True:
> --> 282             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>     283             if status != CONTINUE:
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
>     250             # sending a valid response.
> --> 251             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
>     252                                      " response")
> 
> ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end
> closed connection without response',))
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-16-598f53da7af3> in <module>()
>       3 import requests
>       4 url ='http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/einfo.fcgi'
> ----> 5 r = requests.get(url)
>       6 r.content
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params,
> **kwargs)
>      67 
>      68     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
> ---> 69     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>      70 
>      71 
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url,
> **kwargs)
>      48 
>      49     session = sessions.Session()
> ---> 50     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>      51     # By explicitly closing the session, we avoid leaving sockets open which
>      52     # can trigger a ResourceWarning in some cases, and look like a memory leak
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self,
> method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout,
> allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
>     466         }
>     467         send_kwargs.update(settings)
> --> 468         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     469 
>     470         return resp
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self,
> request, **kwargs)
>     574 
>     575         # Send the request
> --> 576         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     577 
>     578         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
> 
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self,
> request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>     410 
>     411         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
> --> 412             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>     413 
>     414         except MaxRetryError as e:
> 
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote
> end closed connection without response',))
```

Answer (score 19):

try use request session.

```
import requests
MAX_RETRIES = 20
url ='http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/einfo.fcgi'

session = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=MAX_RETRIES)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
session.mount('http://', adapter)

r = session.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code and what it does exactly?

Comment: max_retries -- The maximum number of retries each connection should attempt. Note, this applies only to failed DNS lookups, socket connections and connection timeouts, never to requests where data has made it to the server. By default, Requests does not retry failed connections. If you need granular control over the conditions under which we retry a request, import urllib3's Retry class and pass that instead. source: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter

Answer (score 4):

My symptoms were very similar:

The Splunk HEC library that was giving off errors like:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

and when going thru flask it looked like

```
{
  "message": "('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"
}
```

This answer worked for me, while the addition of timeouts and retries with the HTTP Adapter did not help.

https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/HEC-Error-Connection-closed-by-peer/m-p/473363/highlight/true#M81317

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511852/999943

Adding a close header to the request:

The Connection: close header is added to the actual request:

```
r = requests.post(url=url, data=body, headers={'Connection':'close'})
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
import requests     

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True,headers={
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
})
```

Comment: Please explain how this code snippet will answer the question. What was the issue and what your solution provide ?

Comment: This answer fixed my problem. I had a CS-CART site with Cloudflare, and the API calls not working without this user agent (same call with Curl worked, only the python request lib not).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was HTTP mocking library. I was using [HTTPretty](https://httpretty.readthedocs.io) to mock `requests` on my tests.

HTTPretty library is pretty young and while it clearly states that [it will raise `UnmockedError` if any unmocked URL is requested during testing](https://httpretty.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/httpretty/errors.html?highlight=UnmockedError), it didn't raise it in `requests` library. So, if you are using any HTTP mocking library, especially the ones that mock the socket directly, you might get this error.

The error fades away out of scope in HTTPretty:

```
httpretty.enable()

# error might occur here

httpretty.disable()

# out of scope
```

> This answer is written for Googlers and might not intersect with the interests of the OP.