# How can I use Python to automate accessing a website through a VPN (providing the login details to said VPN in the code itself)

Tags: python, automation, vpn

I am a beginner programmer. How would I approach this problem? I want to provide Python with certain webpages and certain actions to take on said webpages. The problem is, the webpages are region restricted, so I have to use a VPN constantly. Would there be any way to have Python automatically connect to a vpn service (Mullvad, NordVPN etc) to a specific country while running the code? Thanks.

Comment: You can always cheat and have python make a system call to start the vpn however you would normally do so from the command line

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding VPNs you could use proxies. But if you need to use a VPN I suggest looking at the Google results for your specific provider, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934030/how-do-i-use-nordvpn-servers-as-python-requests-proxies) for Nord.