# Python GET request from live/infinite API endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests

I want to get info from API via Python, which has infinite info updating (it is live - for example live video or live monitoring). So I want to stop this GET request after interval (for example 1 second), then process these information and then repeat this cycle.

Any ideas? (now I am using requests module, but I do not know, how to stop receiving data and then get them)

Comment: Does the API have a parameter where you can send it the required duration of data?

Comment: No. It is Doorbird API

Answer (score 1):

I might be off here, but if you hit an endpoint at a specific time, it should return the JSON at that particular moment. You could then store it and use it in whatever process you have created.

If you want to hit it again, you would just use requests to hit the endpoint.

Comment: What do you mean? When I send reqeust, API starts to sending data.

Comment: I assume you are doing the live video request API, correct? If so, have you tried response.close() to close the connection?

Comment: If say you are using response.get('your url here'), try response.close() to close the connection.

Comment: But requests.get("url") doesn't stop, so .close() is unreachable

Comment: I would suggest posting your code and the responses you are seeing in your initial post. It will be easier to figure it out if we see everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115126/python-requests-close-http-connection. I would suggest trying this.