# Mitigating TCP connection resets in AWS Fargate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using Amazon ECS on AWS Fargate, My instances can access the internet, but the connection drops after **350** seconds. On average, out of 100 times, my service is getting **ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer** error approximately 5 times. I found a couple of suggestions to fix that issue on my server-side code, see [here](https://paramount.tech/blog/2021/07/26/mitigation-of-connection-reset-in-aws.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout)

**Cause**

If a connection that's using a NAT gateway is idle for 350 seconds or more, the connection times out.

When a connection times out, a NAT gateway returns an RST packet to any resources behind the NAT gateway that attempt to continue the connection (it does not send a FIN packet).

**Solution**

To prevent the connection from being dropped, you can initiate more traffic over the connection. Alternatively, you can enable TCP keepalive on the instance with a value less than 350 seconds.

**Existing Code:**

```
url = "url to call http"
params = {
   "year": year,
   "month": month
}
response = self.session.get(url, params=params)
```

*To fix that I am currently using a band-aid retry logic solution using* **tenacity**,

```
@retry(
        retry=(
            retry_if_not_exception_type(
                HTTPError
            )  # specific: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
        ),
        reraise=True,
        wait=wait_fixed(2),
        stop=stop_after_attempt(5),
)
def call_to_api():
    url = "url to call HTTP"
    params = {
       "year": year,
       "month": month
    }
    response = self.session.get(url, params=params)
```

So my basic question is how can I use python requests correctly to do any of the below solutions,

- Close the connection before 350 seconds of inactivity
- Enable Keep-Alive for TCP connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting solution for the future user who will face this issue while working on **AWS Farget + NAT**,

We need to set the TCP keepalive settings to the values dictated by our server-side configuration, this PR helps me a lot to fix my issue: https://github.com/customerio/customerio-python/pull/70/files

```
import socket
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection


HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = ( HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
        (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 300),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60)
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the "Close the connection before 350 seconds of inactivity" problem, there seems to be a [read timeout](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts) parameter you can pass to the `session.get()` function call.

According to the doc *"it’s the number of seconds that the client will wait between bytes sent from the server"*.
Which, to me, looks like an inactivity timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking that the connection is automatically closing by request session, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68124995/1138192, correct me if I am missing something here.

Comment: It seems that the connection is closed if you use the `Session` object as a context manager. That's for sure a good idea and probably best practice too. But I don't think it will solve your problem. For the connection to be closed, the `get` method needs to return, so that the context manager `__exit__` method is called. In your case, it seems that the `get` is "stuck" while waiting for a response until the NAT gateway decides to timeout the connection.