# PHP-FPM fastcgi_finish_request() not working as expected

Tags: kohana-3, php

I read @Dmitri 's original [example of how to use fastcgi_finish_request()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4236040) question and tried to follow the example in the answer in my Kohana 3.1 setup in index.php:

```
echo Request::factory()
    ->execute()
    ->send_headers()
    ->body();
```

Right after that, I added:

```
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(5);
```

Initially, I thought it worked. But then I realised in only worked for every **other** request. Example:

1. Navigate to localhost (works, no pause)
2. Click link to localhost/controller (pause 5 seconds)
3. Click another link to localhost/controller (works again, no pause)

And it continues on like that. Am I missing something? Like maybe a setting in php5-fpm config file?

Running PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch, Nginx

Comment: Sorry guys, I asked this almost exactly a year ago. I can't find the relevant code anymore but will update update this question as soon as I have time to get back to it. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the server-response itself (which you can control with the `fastcgi_finish_request` function and rest assured it works that way), there can be other resources that is blocking the (next) script from starting right ahead.

This can be file-lockings (popular for session) and other stuff. As you have not shared much code and we do not see your Kohana configuration you should take a look which components you use and which resources they acquire.

Answer (score 2):

Call `session_write_close()` before you call `fastcgi_finish_request()` to resolve this issue:

```
session_write_close();
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(5);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that wasn't it.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this helped solve my problems. Thank you so much. Spent hours trying to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Is it because your web server only handles one php instance at a time and it is still exciting the previous script?