# php close connection and continue on background

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, fastcgi, background-process

How can i close the connection and continue on background on the following environment ?

SERVER : Microsoft-IIS/7.0

PHP support : (run as FastCGI application)

PHP version : 5.2.17

Host : Shared , CRON : NO

I tried many existing solutions , it works on Local wamp server or in a PHP LINUX server but not in IIS.

```
// buffer all upcoming output
ob_start();
echo "Here's my awesome web page";

// get the size of the output
$size = ob_get_length();

// send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');

// flush all output
@ob_end_flush();
@ob_flush();
@flush();

// close current session
if (session_id()) session_write_close();

sleep(10);

// DO SOME BACKGROUND WORK ...
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what is your expected behavior

Comment: @DevZer0 Updated Question, i need to do some background activity.

Comment: Lots of things can go wrong, including downstream cacheing, and compression messing up the `Content-Length`. You tagged CodeIgniter; that adds its own layer of buffering as well. If there's a never-fails way to accomplish this, I've never seen it. (So if you find one, please let me know!)

Comment: @Jerry response buffer limit is the another problem i am currently facing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call this: `fastcgi_finish_request();`

See also:

- [example of how to use fastcgi_finish_request()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236040/example-of-how-to-use-fastcgi-finish-request)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php (and comments)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php (and comments)

Comment: fastcgi_finish_request is PHP-FPM SAPI specific function, unavailable in standard php-fcgi binary (used by Apache [mod_fcgid, mod_fastcgi], nginx, lighttpd etc).