# How to execute php code after html page load

Tags: javascript, php

after full html page load want to execute some php api's & script and display response

```
<html>
<body>
content 
<?php
//some php script execute after full page load
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258088/can-php-run-after-the-page-is-loaded

Comment: Another way: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236040/example-of-how-to-use-fastcgi-finish-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236040/example-of-how-to-use-fastcgi-finish-request)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP is a server-side programming language. It gets executed when you request a page. So you cannot execute it after the page has been loaded.
If you need to check if something has loaded on the client side, you'll have to use a client-side programming language like JavaScript.

That way you can make a request to a PHP file (which will be executed) and get process everything that is returned by the file.

You can do this using JavaScript or [jQuery](https://jquery.com) (a JavaScript library):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
    $(document).ready( function() { 
        $('#some_id').load('php-file.php'); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: A round of applause for an explanatory solution, Tom :)

Answer (score 7):

To do so you could make use of the Ajax calls after the page is rendered ,

```
$(window).load(function(){ /*This allows to execute your code after the  page is rendered fully */ 
    $.get("<path to php file>", function(data){
     /* you can then process the ajax response as needed */
    });
})
```

You can this ([Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)) ,to be helpful to load your script after page load