# How do I end a PHP connection with a client and still log to an external service?

Tags: php, multithreading

I was wanting to log to Keen.IO (an external logger service) after a php session was over but I didn't want the user to need to wait for that process to finish. Is there a way to end the connection with the client before this happens? Additionally, I didn't want the client session to hang if for some reason the Keen.IO service goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can forcefully close the connection with [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) if you're using PHP-FPM. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236290/5113242) for more details.

```
<?php
echo 'Page content';
fastcgi_finish_request(); // cut connection
do_logging();
```

I have tried other methods before (eg. setting HTTP headers to disable keep-alive and defining the response length), but none of them worked. So if you're not using FPM, you're out of luck.