# Closing a connection early with PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying to complete a script that sends the proper notification to a users browser to close the connection, but allows the server to keep processing a request. My code is based on what I've seen on:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172

and

[close a connection early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early)

```
ob_start();
echo ('Text the user will see');
$size = ob_get_length();
ignore_user_abort(); // optional
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Connection: close");
// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(5);
//just a test to see if the script continues to run 
file_put_contents("trash/".date('dmY-H_i_s_1').".txt", "Some text.");
file_put_contents("trash/".date('dmY-H_i_s_2').".txt", "Some text.");
file_put_contents("trash/".date('dmY-H_i_s_3').".txt", "Some text.");
```

When I go to run the script, sometimes it will create the first file but not write the text to it. Sometimes it doesn't create any files. If I run the script with the return early code commented out, all three files are created just fine. Zlib compression is turned off. Any ideas?

Comment: if you want the server to stop processing the request use: exit() or die()

Comment: You mean you want to close the connection to the browser, but keep doing stuff in PHP in the background? Don't think you can, unless you spawn a separate process.

Comment: @FeidaKila: How will he be able to work with files after `exit`ing or `die`ing?

Comment: Yes, I do want the server to continue doing work in the background after closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use php in fastcgi mode and then you can use the function
fastcgi_finish_request();
it will do exactly what you need - it will close the connection to the browser but the rest of the script will continue to run to the end.

http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features

It's much better than relying on output buffering.

Comment: I would love to give it a try, however our production environment is not currently setup to use fastcgi and it is not an immediate option to switch it over.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can set your extra processing to take place with [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).</strike>

Basically, you register something to take place after you script finishes and sends all output to the user. That way the script can keep running for a while after that doing whatever cleanup or what not is needed.

#### Update: My bad, that no long applies after PHP 4.1

The [links you gave](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#104541) and the [other stuff](http://www.zulius.com/how-to/close-browser-connection-continue-execution/) I found seems to state you are doing it right. Are you sure there isn't an error or script timeout going on? **What does the PHP error log state?**

Comment: No errors in the error log. Its like it try's to execute the next command after the final flush and then goes away after that.

Answer (score 0):

`ignore_user_abort()` must have a non-null parameter for it to actually ignore user abort. Otherwise it just returns the current ignore setting without changing anything. so you'd need

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```