# OpenGraph watch action - less than 50% watched

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the Javascript SDK to contact the API.

Using Built-in Watch action:

> When a user watches less than 50% of a video, or if a user removes a watch activity from your app/site, you should also remove the corresponding action instance that was published to Open Graph by invoking the following call

*DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[watch action instance id]*

My problem is with when the user navigates away from the page.

I've tried to use the jquery unload method to make the delete call to the API but it fails to. I've also tried using ajax to make the call synchronously but this holds/freezes the browser for at least 5 seconds on average.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don’t you just, instead of _removing_ when watched less than 50%, only _publish_ the action when the user has watched _more_ than 50% in the first place …?

Comment: That's a possibility. I would love to follow the FB requirements - publish action after 10 seconds, then update on leave. Not only would it follow the requirements but it would maximise visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried to use the jquery unload method to make the delete call to the API but it fails to.

Well, that’s a problem with the call being asynchronous. Your unload handler fires, starts the request, and then the browser navigates away from the page. *Wait, what, there’s a request still running? Let’s terminate that, since I’m about to load and display another page anyway …*

> I've also tried using ajax to make the call synchronously but this holds/freezes the browser for at least 5 seconds on average.

If that’s how long your call takes, then I see no realistic way of shortening that.

You could try setting up a script that terminates straight away, without giving a return value (or a *yeah OK, go on with your stuff, browser* response) – and finishes the rest (making the actual API call) afterwards, server-side.

Comment: Any suggestions for a server-side solution? I've been looking into message queues but it seems like a pretty complex solution for a problem which should be fairly simple.

Comment: As I suggested, one possible soultion would be to have the server-side script close the connection and then continue its work - for example in PHP this should be possible as described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early