# Run PHP script without webpage waiting for it to finish

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I have some basic website tracking software that sends a `JSON object` with `jQuery AJAX` from a webpage cross-domain to a server where the data is processed by a `php` script. This is triggered on `window.onbeforeunload`.

When benchmarking my `php` script I have realised that the client website on a different domain is still waiting for the php script to finish running before loading the next page. For example, a visitor to a client site navigates to another page. We send the `JSON object` cross domain to the server to process it. If I add `sleep(30);` to my `php` script the client website will not load the next page until this `php` script finishes (30+ seconds).

I do not need to return any values after running this script so how can I ensure this `php` script runs without having any impact on the client site?

I hope I've explained myself well enough. Ask any questions if I haven't, thanks.

SOLUTION:

This is what worked for me (http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#93441):

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
ob_start();
echo ('Text user will see');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
ob_end_clean();

//do processing here
sleep(5);

echo('Text user will never see');
//do some processing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **For PHP-fpm:**

  To close connection with client (send response), but continue running script and processing some data, this function can help you - [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net//manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)
- **For apache**:

  See this link - [close a connection early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early)

Comment: Thanks, from what I understand this looks like a good solution. However I am getting an error: `Call to undefined function  fastcgi_finish_request()`. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are using apache instead of nginx+fpm, i think this function works only for fpm.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early

Comment: Yeah, it's seems you are using apache, so apache haven't analogue of this function, but link which @KIKOSoftware has provided is pretty good. May be it's also a good idea to refactor your JS-script so that it do not wait a response from the server ( make it asynchronous )

Comment: Thanks all and @KIKO Software, that did the trick. Solution and link above.