# PHP Symfony Silex, response is not sent before finish()

Tags: php, symfony

What I'm trying to do is this: User makes an API call, I give the response, and then I start doing actions that take long such as sending emails. (Emails take long because I'm using SMTP, so swiftmailer does that in a synchronous way.)

According to the [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#finish-middleware) finish() should be called after the response has been sent. When I test this however, this seems to be not the case. My client side stays waiting until the finish() is done.

Server side code:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello', function (Request $r) use($app) {

    return $app->json("I should load within a few milliseconds.");
});


$app->finish(function() use () {
    //Pretend to do some slow action afterwards
    sleep(5);

});

$app->run();
```

Now if I load the page `http://localhost/hello` it will take 5 seconds for it to load. While my expectation is that it would load instantaneous. Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

## Update:

Technically The accepted answer did what I asked for it. Practically I found a different solution:

I was looking for a way to get my emails sent in a way that the end-user wouldn't have to wait for it. For my purposes I switched over to using `Swift_MailTransport` instead of `Swift_SmtpTransport`, and configured exim4 locally as a smarthost. This way the email gets handed off to Exim4 and the script continues immediately.

If you are looking for other long processes to execute than just emails, have a look at message queues such as [Beanstalk](https://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), I read great things about them.

The accepted answer below does work (also follow the links in the comments to the documentation page), but I found the solution not clean enough for my particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

No, you don't. The content of the web response is send before that the `finish` filters are run, but the output is not [flush](http://php.net/manual/it/function.flush.php). Try to add

```
 ob_flush();
 flush();
```

before `sleep(5)`, and it will work as you might expect.

You may want to [spool](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) emails like the [SwiftmailerBundle](https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailSenderListener.php#L46). See [swiftmailer.use_spool](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/swiftmailer.html).

> By default, the Swiftmailer provider sends the emails using the
>   KernelEvents::TERMINATE event, which is fired after the response has
>   been sent.

Comment: Flushing gives me half of what I want. I do indeed see the text immediately, but the little spinner still goes on for 5 seconds. As if the server says "hold on, there might be more". Could that be handled as well?

Comment: That's because your browser use `keep-alive`. The `Connection: close` header lets the browser know that it should not maintain a persistent connection: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138374/711206).

Comment: What I don't understand is that Symfony's `Reponse` use `fastcgi_finish_request`, so all this should not be a problem. Are you using php 5.3+?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.12 on this dev machine. (WAMP) 
Could I add the `Connection: Close` header myself in `->after()`?