# Is it possible to make a single PHP script ignore FastCGI's output buffer?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, output-buffering

I have a PHP script that needs to process some more information in the background after returning the response.

I made it work by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early) as well as turning off [FastCGI Output Buffer](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidoutputbuffersize):

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
</IfModule>
```

It won't work without turning off FastCGI Output Buffer.

However, I only have one script that needs this. It would be nice if I can keep FastCGI Output Buffer for all other scripts.

Is it possible to just make one PHP script ignore FastCGI Output Buffer?

Comment: It sounds like you need to run a task in the background, not futz around with output buffering.

Comment: But the user needs to initiate it with data.

Comment: Yeah so whatever function this is takes its parameters, performs its immediate tasks [eg: content generation], starts the background task, and returns. The page is delivered as expected without having to selectively disable output buffering, and whatever long-running thing you started is still going in the background.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I need. Please add an answer with some code example. Like I said, the script I took from the other post's answer won't work without turning off FastCGI Output Buffer. The user gets the response after the long-running task finishes.

Comment: In that specific case, you could just prefill the (default) buffer, e.g. `echo str_repeat(' ', 65537);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use nested Apache directives to check the request URI.
Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/path/to/script.php'">
        FcgidOutputBufferSize 0
    </If>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What if I only need this for a specific function in the script?

Comment: @Shawn Sorry I don't know how to do that. Hopefully someone else who knows can answer.

Comment: cPanel keeps throwing me syntax error with your solution. Any idea?

Comment: @Shawn I'm not sure why there is a syntax error. I used this page as a reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#examples. It looks like it should work. The error doesn't give you any more detail?