# Yii connection handler: How to run code in background after page execution?

Tags: php, yii

I found some `core php` code from Google. I tested this code is working fine. But While I am using this code in my Yii application this code is not working.
Please check my code below:

```
/* filename: test.php */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
ini_set("error_log", "error.log");

echo "We'll email you as soon as this is done.";

$size = ob_get_length();

header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');

// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
//ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(30);
/* notification and other code here */
error_log("Background process end");
```

When I am testing above code in separate file like `test.php` this is working fine. But Not working in Yii controller action.

I have set sleep 30 seconds of my background process execution time. 1st time while I hit my controller action in browser this is working and Page reload couple of microseconds after. While again I refresh this page or any other pages That pages reloading until my 1st execution not done.

Ref:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

[close a connection early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around try

```
$cmd = "php somescript.php $"
shell_exec( $cmd )
```

Or implement a Multithread as shown here!
[How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Comment: My PHP version 7.1. I am unable to install multithread. Could you suggest me any dll file. I have used Windows7