# Jquery Send Ajax and no wait response for sending other ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, no-response

I have an ajax that call to a server and run a long process (this process is writing the status on a database).

I have other ajax (recursively) to get the status of the long process and set the params on a Progress Bar.

My problem is that the second ajax not start until the first one finishes. Is there a way to send the first ajax and no wait for a response?

Any ideas?

I appreciate any suggestion, I am a little bit tired about this issue.

If there is another method to send a long process and get the status of the long process, tell me, please.

Thank you!

This is my code, in case it's helps

```js
executeProgressBar(1, token);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  url: "/long_process",
  data: form_data,
  success: function (response) {
    //NOTHING
  }
});

function executeProgressBar(start, token) {

  if (start == 1) {

    //reset progress bar
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
    $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
    $('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress', '0');

  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/progress_bar_status",
    data: { token: token, sleep: 0 },
    success: function (response) {

      $('.progress-bar').css('width', response['percentage'] + '%');
      $('.progress-bar').text(response['percentage'] + '%');
      $('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress', response['percentage']);

      $('#done').text(response['executed']);
      $('.execute-time').text('tiempo');

      if (response.percentage == 100) {
        $('.end-process').show();
      } else {
        executeProgressBar(0, token);
      }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus == 'parsererror') {
        textStatus = 'Technical error: Unexpected response returned by server. Sending stopped.';
      }
      alert(textStatus);
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

I solved whit this code on the server side - php

```
        /************** Close connection and return echo message **************/
        ob_end_clean();
        header("Connection: close");
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        ob_start();
        echo('text response to ajax');
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Content-Length: $size");
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();

        // if you're using sessions, this prevents subsequent requests
        // from hanging while the background process executes
        if (session_id()) {
            session_write_close();
        }

        /************** background process starts here **************/
```

View in this post: [How do I close a connection early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/how-do-i-close-a-connection-early)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `executeProgressBar` instantly instead of waiting for the first AJAX call to complete. Call the `executeProgressBar` function in the `success` method callback and pass it to the `executeProgressBar` function and modify the parameters like the example below.

Be sure to build a check in that lets the recursive function know when to stop.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "/long_process",
    data: form_data,
    success: function (response) {
        executeProgressBar(1, token, response);
    }
});

function executeProgressBar(start, token, response) {

    if (start == 1) {

        //reset progress bar
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress', '0');

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/progress_bar_status",
        data: {token: token, sleep: 0},
        success: function (response) {

            $('.progress-bar').css('width', response['percentage'] + '%');
            $('.progress-bar').text(response['percentage'] + '%');
            $('.progress-bar').attr('data-progress', response['percentage']);

            $('#done').text(response['executed']);
            $('.execute-time').text('tiempo');

            if (response.percentage == 100) {
                $('.end-process').show();
            } else {
                executeProgressBar(0, token, response);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (textStatus == 'parsererror') {
                textStatus = 'Technical error: Unexpected response returned by server. Sending stopped.';
            }
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The problem was that the first ajax takes 10 minutes. With your solution, when the first ajax finish, the status is 100% (With the extra code included on my post, second ajax should me inside the first now)