# Asynchronous shell exec in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, shell

I've got a PHP script that needs to invoke a shell script but doesn't care at all about the output. The shell script makes a number of SOAP calls and is slow to complete, so I don't want to slow down the PHP request while it waits for a reply. In fact, the PHP request should be able to exit without terminating the shell process.

I've looked into the various `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `pcntl_fork()`, etc. functions, but none of them seem to offer exactly what I want. (Or, if they do, it's not clear to me how.) Any suggestions?

Comment: No matter which solution you choose, you should also consider using `nice` and `ionice` to prevent the shell script from overwhelming your system (e.g. `/usr/bin/ionice -c3 /usr/bin/nice -n19`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

If it "doesn't care about the output", couldn't the exec to the script be called with the `&` to background the process?

**EDIT** - incorporating what @[AdamTheHut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103/adamthehutt) commented to this post, you can add this to a call to `exec`:

```
" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"
```

That will redirect both `stdio` (first `>`) and `stderr` (`2>`) to `/dev/null` and run in the background.

There are other ways to do the same thing, but this is the simplest to read.

---

An alternative to the above double-redirect:

```
" &> /dev/null &"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it needs a little more than an ampersand. I got it working by appending "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" to the exec() call. 

Although I have to admit I'm not exactly sure what that does.

Comment: that redirects stdio to /dev/null and stderr to /dev/null .. good catch on the addition to the call

Comment: Definitely the way to go if you want fire and forget with php and apache. A lot of production Apache and PHP environments will have pcntl_fork() disabled.

Comment: Just a note for `&> /dev/null &`, xdebug won't generate logs if you use this. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883171/xdebug-start-trace-behaving-strangely/4888138#4888138

Comment: It'd be more efficient to close the FDs rather than re-opening them to /dev/null: `<&- 1<&- 2<&-`

Comment: how do you kill the process you just executed?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - What, exactly, does `<&- 1<&- 2<&-` do?  I googled it, and I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @MichaelJMulligan it closes the file descriptors. That said, despite the efficiency gains, in hindsight, using `/dev/null` is the better practice, as writing to closed FDs causes errors, whereas attempts to read or write to `/dev/null` simply silently do nothing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's the method I went with in the end.  I tried closing the FDs, but my script (in this case a php script) just threw to the background in a stopped state until I foregrounded it.  It took command line arguments, so that may have been part of it

Comment: Background scripts will be killed when restarting apache ... just be aware of this for very long jobs or if you are unlucky timing-wise and you wonder why your job disappeared ...

Comment: Just wanted to share my experience: here, PHP didn't run the process in background until I explicitly used `2>/dev/null >/dev/null`. Trying to redirect the output to a file, for example, made apache hang until the execution finished. So my approach was to "pipe" the output to `tee` before redirecting to `/dev/null`. Like this:

`shell_exec('my_script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a mylog.log 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &');`

Comment: This works if the php script ends normally, but if I end the process by pressing "ctrl+c" in the command line, for example, the background process exits prematurely. Any ideas on how to prevent that?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same under Windows?

Comment: @fritzmg - I don't know: never tried doing something like that on a Windows machine

Comment: @fritzmg Look at my answer; it works under Windows as well as Unix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40243588/1412157

Comment: This answer provides a more comprehensive solution if you need to be able to check if the process is still running: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966/814160

Comment: @kapeels not a perfect solution, but you could use `~/log/mylog.log` instead of `/dev/null` to get the output logged

Answer (score 58):

I used **at** for this, as it is really starting an independent process.

```
<?php
    `echo "the command"|at now`;
?>
```

Comment: in some situations this is absolutely the best solution. it was the only one that worked for me to release a "sudo reboot" ("echo 'sleep 3; sudo reboot' | at now") from a webgui AND finish rendering the page .. on openbsd

Comment: if the user you run apache (usually `www-data`) doesn't have the permissions to use `at` and you can't configure it to, you can try to use `<?php exec('sudo sh -c "echo \"command\" | at now" ');` If `command` contains quotes, see [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.escapeshellarg.php) to save you headaches

Comment: Well thinking about it, to get sudo to run sh isn't the best idea, as it basically gives sudo a root access to everything. I reverted to use `echo "sudo command" | at now` and commenting `www-data` out in `/etc/at.deny`

Comment: @Julien maybe you could make a shell script with the sudo command and launch it instead. as long as you aren't passing any user submitted values to said script

Comment: `at` package (and command) is non default for some linux distributions. Also it is need to be running `atd` service. This solution may be a hard to understand because of explanation lack.

Answer (score 39):

To all Windows users: I found a good way to run an asynchronous PHP script (actually it works with almost everything).

It's based on popen() and pclose() commands. And works well both on Windows and Unix.

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
```

Original code from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: this only execute a file, not work if using php/python/node etc

Comment: @davidvalentino Correct, and that's fine! If you would like to execute a PHP/Pyhton/NodeJS script you have to actually call the executable and pass to it your script. E.g.: you don't put in your terminal `myscript.js` but instead, you will write `node myscript.js`. That is: **node** is the executable, **myscript.js** is the, well, script to execute. There's a huge difference between executable and script.

Comment: right thats no problem in that case,, in other cases example like need to run laravel artisan, `php artisan` just put comment here so no need tracing why it wont work with commands

Comment: Short, sweet and it works (Windows + Wamp - running the command:
execInBackground("curl ".$url);

Answer (score 26):

On linux you can do the following:

```
$cmd = 'nohup nice -n 10 php -f php/file.php > log/file.log & printf "%u" $!';
$pid = shell_exec($cmd);
```

This will execute the command at the command prompty and then just return the PID, which you can check for > 0 to ensure it worked.

This question is similar: [Does PHP have threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)

Comment: This answer would be easier to read if you included only the bare essentials (eliminating the `action=generate var1_id=23 var2_id=35 gen_id=535` segment).  Also, since OP asked about running a shell script, you don't need the PHP-specific portions.  The final code would be: `$cmd = 'nohup nice -n 10 /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/log/file.log & printf "%u" $!';`

Comment: Also, as a note from one who has "been there before", anyone reading this might consider using not just `nice` but also `ionice`.

Comment: What does "%u" $! do exactly?

Comment: @Twigs `&` runs preceding code in the background, then `printf` is used for formatted output of the `$!` variable which contains the PID

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried all sorts of solutions I was finding to output to a log with an async PHP shell call and yours is the only one that's fulfilled all of the criteria.

Answer (score 13):

[php-execute-a-background-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process#45966) has some good suggestions.  I think mine is pretty good, but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 6):

In Linux, you can start a process in a new independent thread by appending an ampersand at the end of the command

```
mycommand -someparam somevalue &
```

In Windows, you can use the "start" DOS command

```
start mycommand -someparam somevalue
```

Comment: On Linux, the parent can still block until the child has finished running if it's trying to read from an open file handle held by the subprocess (ie. stdout), so this isn't a complete solution.

Comment: Tested `start` command on windows, it does not run asynchronously... Could you include the source where you got that information from?

Comment: @Alph.Dev please take a look to my answer if you're using Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40243588/1412157

Comment: @mynameis Your answer shows exactly why the start command was NOT working. Its because of the `/B` parameter. I've explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34612967/1709903

Answer (score 6):

the right way(!) to do it is to

1. fork()
2. setsid()
3. execve()

fork forks, setsid tell the current process to become a master one (no parent), execve tell the calling process to be replaced by the called one. so that the parent can quit without affecting the child.

```
 $pid=pcntl_fork();
 if($pid==0)
 {
   posix_setsid();
   pcntl_exec($cmd,$args,$_ENV);
   // child becomes the standalone detached process
 }

 // parent's stuff
 exit();
```

Comment: The problem with pcntl_fork() is that you are not supposed to use it when running under a web server, as the OP does (besides, the OP have tried this already).

Answer (score 6):

I used this...

```
/** 
 * Asynchronously execute/include a PHP file. Does not record the output of the file anywhere.  
 * Relies on the PHP_PATH config constant.
 *
 * @param string $filename  file to execute
 * @param string $options   (optional) arguments to pass to file via the command line
 */ 
function asyncInclude($filename, $options = '') {
    exec(PHP_PATH . " -f {$filename} {$options} >> /dev/null &");
}
```

(where `PHP_PATH` is a const defined like `define('PHP_PATH', '/opt/bin/php5')` or similar)

It passes in arguments via the command line. To read them in PHP, see [argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Answer (score 5):

I also found [Symfony Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously) useful for this.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
// ... run process in background
$process->start();

// ... do other things

// ... if you need to wait
$process->wait();

// ... do things after the process has finished
```

See how it works in its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/729f0f798ebf13f17a79e2431bbcc1fd5c515552/Process.php#L250).

Comment: Warning: if you don't wait, the process will be killed when the request ends

Comment: Perfect tool, that is based on `proc_*` internal functions.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I found that truly worked for me was:

```
shell_exec('./myscript.php | at now & disown')
```

Comment: 'disown' is a Bash built-in and doesn't work with shell_exec() this way. I tried `shell_exec("/usr/local/sbin/command.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | at now & disown")` and all I get is: `sh: 1: disown: not found`

Answer (score 2):

You can also run the PHP script as **daemon** or **cronjob**: `#!/usr/bin/php -q`

Answer (score 1):

Use a named fifo.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo trigger
while true; do
    read < trigger
    long_running_task
done
```

Then whenever you want to start the long running task, simply write a newline (nonblocking to the trigger file.

As long as your input is smaller than `PIPE_BUF` and it's a single `write()` operation, you can  write arguments into the fifo and have them show up as `$REPLY` in the script.

Answer (score 1):

without use queue, you can use the [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) like this:

```
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w")    //here curaengine log all the info into stderror
    );
    $command = 'ping stackoverflow.com';
    $process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not use  `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` on Windows, so I use `proc_open` instead. I run PHP 7.4.23 on Windows 11.

This is my code.

```php
function run_php_async($value, $is_windows)
{
    if($is_windows)
    {
        $command = 'php -q '.$value." ";
        echo 'COMMAND '.$command."\r\n";
        proc_open($command, [], $pipe);    
    }
    else
    {
        $command = 'php -q '.$value." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &";
        echo 'COMMAND '.$command."\r\n";
        shell_exec($command);    
    }
}
$tasks = array();

$tasks[] = 'f1.php';
$tasks[] = 'f2.php';
$tasks[] = 'f3.php';
$tasks[] = 'f4.php';
$tasks[] = 'f5.php';
$tasks[] = 'f6.php';

$is_windows = true;

foreach($tasks as $key=>$value)
{
    run_php_async($value, $is_windows);
    echo 'STARTED AT '.date('H:i:s')."\r\n";
}
```

In each files to be execute, I put delay this:

```php
<?php
sleep(mt_rand(1, 10));
file_put_contents(__FILE__.".txt", time());
```

All files are executed asynchronously.