# xdebug_start_trace behaving strangely

Tags: xdebug, php

I'm trying to reduce my script memory usage even more. I am trying to make my script generate output with xdebug to analyse the memory usage. It's a CLI based script has shebang

`#!/usr/local/bin/php -q`

I pass a parameter to it and check it with

`$argc > 1 && is_numeric( $argv[1] )`

When I login to ssh and do `./script.php 90` and add this code,

```
if( $argv[1] == 90 ) {
       xdebug_start_trace('/var/www/html/logs/' . rand(1,9999999) );
}
```

I see the output file in the `logs` folder.

But when I put the `xdebug_start_trace` without the `if` statement in production script, no output file is created.

The `script.php` is called from another php file, placed in another folder, so I use absolute path in the filename and call it using `exec` and append `&> /dev/null &` to it, so it runs in the background.

This is driving me crazy! Help, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why this occurred but I got an error

`PHP Notice:  Function trace already started in /var/www/html/script.php on line 9` [Check "Edit" for info]

Although, there is no code that triggers this `xdebug_start_trace();`.

So I put `xdebug_stop_trace();` before `xdebug_start_trace();`, everything works fine.

Strange.

Edit: I was getting the above error as I had set auto_trace to On in php.ini

Also, turns out that if you are append `&> /dev/null &` to the command, no xdebug log is generated. However, if I do `&> /dev/null` (notice the last `&` ), xdebug generates logs. This is probably related to custom output xdebug must be using internally. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

You mean ...

```
if( $argv[1] == 90 ) {
       xdebug_start_trace('/var/www/html/logs/' . rand(1,9999999) );
}
```

... leads to a trace-file and ...

```
xdebug_start_trace('/var/www/html/logs/' . rand(1,9999999) );
```

... just leaving out the condiional statement gives you none?

And well, I really cannot believe that the tracing starts out of no where ... so there has to be a function call somewhere. Given your description it seems like your setup is pretty messed up. So I don't think your problem is in any way related to XDebug, but this trace-phenomenon is just a random symptom you happend to notice.

Try to set up a scripting which is as simple as possible and still gives you this. Then post again what's going on, b/c your description is also pretty confusing IMHO.

Best

Raffael