# converting using ffmpeg in background

Tags: php, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

i'm witing a php script which convert video into FLV.when the converting is in progress the user has to wait for completion of converting but What I want to do is when the converting is in process the script continue the next lines after shell_exec .How should I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Jared said, try looking at [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)