# how jump from staying for output of shell execute after run in an php script?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec, simultaneous-calls

I have this sample code called main.php:

```
<?php
shell_exec('C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe a.php');
shell_exec('C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe b.php');
?>
```

when execute this script after executing first shell_exec it staying until finishing first shell_exec and then run second.

but I want that script dont stay for finishing first shell_exec and its output and runs second.

now how can I do this?

I have several scripts and I need to run them **Simultaneously** by a **main script** and control them by it. but I dont know that how to run my scripts **Simultaneously** from inside of this **main script**?

**update1:** I cant run a.php and b.php by cron jobs because their finishing time is unknown.
maybe a.php finished after 1 hour or 10 minutes and b.php as same as a.php too.

**update2:** I founded a solution in this page:

[Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

Comment: what is the use-case? Possible solutions would include ajax or for example scheduled jobs if it's just something that needs to run periodically.

Comment: I dont run these scripts by browser. these scripts must run in background

Comment: If you are looking for a shell script, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672719/parallel-execution-of-shell-processes

Comment: @jeroen I dont understand them. I only want a simple way to run an cmd command from inside of a php script and dont stay for its output and execute rest of my script codes :(

Comment: Duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657846/executing-a-shell-script-in-background-with-php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you wish to run a background process on a Windows box.Suggest try this...

```
<?php
    shell_exec('start /b C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe a.php');
    shell_exec('start /b C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe b.php');
?>
```