# No speed difference found when running exec(scp) in the background

Tags: php, asynchronous, exec

I'm trying to copy [asyncronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657846/executing-a-shell-script-in-background-with-php) 10 70 MB video files.

```
exec("scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -i /var/keys/devDevices_rsa MarTianez1.mp4 awong@10.1.1.16:/tmp/test1 2>&1 > out.log", $output, $exitCode);
...
exec("scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -i /var/keys/devDevices_rsa MarTianez10.mp4 awong@10.1.1.16:/tmp/test10 2>&1 > out.log", $output, $exitCode);
```

But I cannot see any time difference if I remove `2>&1 > out.log`'s  from the `scp` commands.

PHP 8.1, Apache2, Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 1):

The order of redirection is important.
`command 2>&1 > out.log` redirects only stdout to file. This happens because the stderr is redirected to stdout before the stdout was redirected to file. The correct order is `command > out.log 2>&1` (which is the same as `command &> out.log`).

Also, to force a process to start in background, you have to add a `&` at the end of the command.

To run your code asynchronously:

```php
exec("scp ... &> out.log &", $output, $exitCode);
```

If you don't need an output file, you can just redirect the output to `/dev/null`:

```php
exec("scp ... &> /dev/null &", $output, $exitCode);
```