# child processes seperate from main process bash shell php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, process

I' am calling sell script from my php code
with

```
foreach ($some_array) {
     shell_exec(nohup $code); 
}
```

like above

I want all `shell_exec` call to work independent from mail process which is php execution that we call shell script

But It's not working as I expected all shell_executions start right after previous one completed

So how can I make this `shell_exec` calls as independent child process that they don't wait each others completation

Thanks in advance

Comment: i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Add the '&' to the end of the command you want to execute so it works in background.

Answer (score 0):

For a sequence of commands, enclose them within parentheses then append the & symbol but be sure to redirect stdout, stderr somewhere otherwise your script will hang waiting e.g.:

```
<?php

exec('( sleep 10; echo "finished" | mail ian@example.com ) &> /dev/null &');

?>
```

See http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I think that the inclusion of `> /dev/null` is important here.

Comment: @soField this isn't mine; I took it from the explanation on php.net.  However, I've done something similar in a website of mine and it works great.

Answer (score -1):

Send them to the background

```
shell_exec("nohup somecommand &");
                              ^---run job in background
```

Comment: Doesn't work, at least in PHP 5.5. Try saving this simple script as `test.php` and running it: `<?php sleep(1); shell_exec('nohup php test.php &'); ?>`. You'll see a growing list of PHP processes in `ps -e`.