# PHP Calling Server Scripts - WILL NOT CONTINUE after call

Tags: php, python, system, exec, nohup

Right, I am calling a Python script in a PHP script. This PHP script needs to continue after the Python script has been called.

I have tried all of the following, yet PHP insists on waiting until the script has responded.

All tried:-

```
system('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' &');
system('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' 2>&1 &');
system('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' < /dev/null 2>&1 &');
exec('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' &');
exec('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' 2>&1 &');
exec('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' < /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Also tried with passthru and without nohup.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [exec doc](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

You should try this instead:

```
exec('nohup python /home/process/script.py -i '.escapeshellarg($location).' &>/dev/null &');
```