# PHP: cross-platform way of running a java program in the background

Tags: php

The java program in question needs to run for a few minutes, write a temporary file and then terminate. So PHP must allow it run in background , instead of the `exec` way of waiting for that program to terminate.

What is a cross-platform way of doing this?

Comment: You mean run a process asynchronously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Comment: can you create a bash script?

Comment: Some more information on the program in question would be good. I'd rather let it run with a cronjob and have 'quite recent' data at hand, if this is an option. Or is the waiting time not relevant at all?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a dup, since the question requires being cross platform and other questions I can find all seem to have *nix specific answers.

Comment: @acrosman , thanks for mentioning that for me! Yes, most answers are *nix dependant and we use Linux and Windows for different phases of its life.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways.  Message Queues would be a great way to handle this.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/ and http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/

They would allow you to asynchronously execute your java in the background without making the user wait.