# 500 (Internal Server Error) php shell_exec

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am using php shell_exec to run a command from jQuery but it keeps timing out.

So my jquery is as follows.

```
var send = {
    url: $(this).data('url')
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/upload",
    data: send,
    //dataType: "json",
    //timeout: 8000,
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

This then calls a function which runs shell_exec

```
function upload(){
    $output = shell_exec("wget {$_POST['url']} 2>&1");      
    echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>";
}
```

Ok this works fine if the url that is posted for wget get is pulling a small file but if wget is getting a file say over 20mb i get 500 (Internal Server Error)

Things i have checked so far
all my php setting file upload limit max file size etc memory limit all i have set to the max.

The thing that i dont get is this worked fine locally but on my hosting i get this error, i have contact my hosting media temple and they have said it is out of their scope of support.

Any suggestion on how to debug further?

Comment: I'll put £100 on [`set_time_limit(0);`](http://php.net/set-time-limit) fixing it. (Put it as the first line of the PHP `upload()` function)

Comment: Also beware of the fact that what you are doing has HUGE security implications.

Comment: @DaveRandom i would like to see how your bet goes ....

Comment: Sorry no tried that i am still getting 500 server internal error

Comment: i can log into my server via terminal as root and run wget url on a huge file and it will work no problem at all, so its got to be a php issue set_time_limit(0); i hope would work but still getting issues ;(

Comment: Try using `passthru()` instead.

Comment: Indeed, `exec()`ing wget is a sucky way to download files to the server.

Comment: What does the apache error log say when this happens?

Comment: What happens if I POST an URI that is "google.com && rm -rf /" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that some kind of reverse proxy - for example Apache balancer - is timing out, whether the PHP script times out or not. You can verify by creating a script such as

```
<?php sleep(60); ?>
```

and experimenting with different delays.

Anyway, upping the time limit would only *appear* to be a solution, since some browsers (e.g. IE8+) will timeout no matter what.

Usually this is solved by detaching the wget process and having a PHP page checking on the process status with a refresh of, say, 5..30 seconds. But many providers take an understandably dim view of detaching processes, since this might hog the memory of a system serving dozens of websites (=paying customers!). So you'd have to check it out with the provider whether the solution is acceptable.

If it is, you can check out " [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php) ".

Comment: hi Islerni thanks for the reply i am on a dedicated server so i shouldn't be hogging memory only from myself correct me if im wrong tho. ill try you method above and post back.

Comment: Ok great narrowing it down i tried sleep 10 20 30 40 50 all returned true but as soon as i went to sleep(60) i got the server 500 internel error...

Comment: You can further narrow checks by setting PHP timeout to, say, 5 seconds, and then running a `sleep(10)` (or better a shell_exec of sleep 10, for I'm not sure whether PHP sleep counts as execution time). That will cause a "true" PHP timeout, and a fatal error, but not a `500 Internal Server Error`. If it does, then you need to dig further; but if it doesn't, and you get a page such as this http://drupal.org/files/issues/ScreenShot003_0.png , then you can be sure it's not a PHP problem and you can get back to your provider asking for an explanation.