# Dynamically Generate Tarball and send through PHP?

Tags: php, download, directory, stdout, tar

I have a directory listing script that I made, and I would like to know what direction I need to go in to make an option for a specific directory to be downloaded as a tarball.  A cronjob would not be acceptable because I would like this to be on demand so CPU cycles aren't wasted on unwanted content, but I would also like caching for content that has been requested.  An ideal solution, which would exclude caching, would be to output the tar command to stdout, but how would I send that through PHP without having to wait for the command to finish?  Some direction on this would be helpful.

Comment: how often does the directory contents change? if infrequently i would crate the tarball with a cronjob say daily. you could also keep track of when the directory changes then just tarball it if it changes.

Comment: This is not ideal for the hosting situation I am in.

Comment: Disregarding the caching, the simplest approach would be `passthru("tar -cz dir/");`

Comment: the information provided is not ideal for answering ;)

Comment: @mario submit that as an answer.  This will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To send it without waiting you could execute the gz command while using "ob_implicit_flush()", not sure if the command will read while still running but you can run it in the background and read from it while outputing into a file or something. You could also check the date on the dir/files and then run the gzip script

Comment: I don't believe this will work, as the return from shell_exec will block it from flushing.

Comment: Not if you run it non-blocking and constantly read the file, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php