# php system() doesnt let the rest of the code , execute

Tags: php, terminal, imacros

I have a PHP script like this:

```
<?php  
  system("firefox http://run.imacros.net/?m=the_macro.iim 2>&1");
  // CODE//  
?>
```

When I run this from terminal, opens my FireFox normally but never run the rest of the code in the script!
If I close the FireFox manually then the script runs the rest of the code.

I want to execute my script without stacking in the system() command.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php (duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

The `2>&1` redirects **stderr** to **stdout**, but you haven't redirected **stdout**, so if any output is generated to either handle, PHP waits. To discard any output to both handles, use

```
system("firefox http://run.imacros.net/?m=the_macro.iim >/dev/null 2>&1");
```