# php restart process in the background spamassassin

Tags: php, exec, background-process, popen, spamassassin

I use popen and ssh.

In one script, i need to restart the service spamassassin with :

```
$spamassassin = "service spamassassin restart &";
$spamassmilter = "service spamass-milter restart &";
shell_exec($spamassassin);
shell_exec($spamassmilter);
```

I want this process restart in the background, because my browser wait the service be restart to stop load the web page.

I try with :

```
$spamassassin = "service spamassassin restart &";
```

and

```
$spamassassin = "service spamassassin restart > exit.txt";
```

and

```
$spamassassin = "nohup service spamassassin restart";
```

But my browser wait the service is restart...

How can i restart the service, without my browser wait until all services are restarted ?

I use **popen, ssh, exec**

**EDIT :**

Finally I resolved my problem thanks to @immulatin for this link

[Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

i use :

```
$spamassassin = "service spamassassin restart &> /dev/null &";
$spamassmilter = "service spamass-milter restart &> /dev/null &";

exec($spamassassin);
exec($spamassmilter);
```

Comment: service restart for SA needs to be done as root not your web user and you don't need the & or anything just "service spamassassin restart"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try using nohup.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

```
<?php
// Note the backticks!
`nohup service spamassassin restart &`
?>
```

Also, make sure the user running apache has enough permissions to restart this service.

Comment: doesn't work. The service can be restarted, but it takes too much time.

Comment: restarting spam assassin does take a while its not an instant job if you want to run it in tandem then look at using a scheduler