# How can I have a php script run another php script separately, so that the first script's output isn't slowed down by the second script?

Tags: php

I have a php page that can be accessed by a user. When they access it, it will return some output. There are actions that don't affect the output, so I would like to find a way to separate those into a different script and have the first script run the second one separately so that the output can be returned faster.

Comment: [This][1] SA answer has a multitude of ways to do it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the easy way

```
exec('php script2.php > /dev/null &');
```

don't forget the path to script2 and sometimes php