# Symfony2 command within an asynchronous subprocess

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, asynchronous, process

I am new on Symfony2 and I got blocked when trying to **run an asynchronous command** like this:

```
class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand{

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('my:command')
        ->setDescription('My command')
        ->addArgument(
            'country',
            InputArgument::REQUIRED,
            'Which country?'
        )
    ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    $country = $input->getArgument('country');


    // Obtain the doctrine manager
    $dm = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager');

   $users = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->findBy( array('country'=>$country));
}}
```

That works perfectly when I call it from my command line:

```
php app/console my:command uk
```

But it doesn't work when I call it trowh a Symfony2 Process:

```
 $process = new Process("php ../app/console my:command $country");
 $process->start();
```

I get a database error: "*[MongoWriteConcernException] 127.0.0.1:27017: not master*"

*I think that means that the process is not getting my database configuration...*

**I just want to run an asynchronous process, is there other way to do it?**

Maybe a way to call the Application Command that do not require the answer to keep going ?

Maybe I need to use injection?

PS: My current command is just a test, at the end it should be an 'expensive' operation...

Comment: Well, I find the solution by myself. Actually it was a silly problem... I've added the environment parameter (**--env=**) to the process and everything worked like a charm: `$process = new Process("php ../app/console my:command $country --env=test");`

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found out what happened...

I use multiple environments: DEV, TEST and PROD.

And I also use differents servers.

So the DEV environment is my own machine with a simple mongodb configuration.
But the TEST environment is on other server with a **replica set** configuration...

Now the error get full sense: *"[MongoWriteConcernException] 127.0.0.1:27017: not master"*

To solve it, I've just added the environment parameter (**--env=**) to the process and everything worked like a charm:

```
$process = new Process("php ../app/console my:command $country --env=test");
```

Actually, to get the correct environment I use this:

```
$this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();
```

Which let's my code as follows:

```
$process = new Process("php ../app/console my:command $country --env=".$this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment());
```

Maybe is not a beautifull way to do it, but it works for me :)

Comment: you should also use the `%kernel.root_dir%` container parameter to create the path to `app/console`

Answer (score 1):

***Disclamer: This might be a bit overkill for what you're trying to do :)***

I would choose an opposite way to do it: `pthreads`

First, quick examination of StackOverflow showed me a really nice example of using `pthreads`: [**Multi-threading is possible in php**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501449/662615)

Then, knowing that you could invoke your command from another command:

http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/06/calling-commands-within-commands-in-symfony2/

... lets you piece all the parts. It's a bit complicated but it does the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jperovic. Yes, like you said, I was looking for something easier ;)

Comment: Ah, I've just read your comment to original question. Glad you resolved the problem. If it's not a problem please add an answer yourself - I'm sure someone will find it useful, sooner or later... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to execute your code completely async in Symfony2/3 there is [AsyncServiceCallBundle](https://github.com/krlove/async-service-call-bundle) for that.

You should just call it like this:

```
$this->get('krlove.async')->call('your_service_id', 'method_name', [$arg1, $arg2]);
```

Internally it uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222445/1667170) approach to run your code in background.