# emulator -avd not working when executing using php shell_exec or exec

Tags: php, terminal, command, exec, shell-exec

command is working fine when I execute it using terminal but not working when I try to execute it using php.

I am executing a command from php using `exec` & `shell_exec` but it is not working.

Please help me to do that.

My code is as below:

```
shell_exec("emulator -avd avd8");
```

and

`exec("emulator -avd avd8`");

When I execute this from terminal it execute the emulator but I execute same from php and it do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You would require Asynchronous task execution in PHP.
Now when you say exec("emulator -avd avd8") the command is executed and php would wait for the output.

try adding '&' at the end may be like exec("emulator -avd avd8 &") to make this a background process.

Refer this link for more information
[Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Comment: I tried with this but it does nothing. I think this is not related my requirement.