# Fire and forget web service/SOAP action

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have the following action registered in my nusoap service:

```
$server->register(
        'testfunction',
        array('value' => 'xsd:string'),
        array( ),
        'urn:test_services',
        'urn:test_services#testfunction'
);
```

...and the function itself:

```
function testfunction($value)
{
    // do something with $value
}
```

I want the action to be "fire and forget", i.e. whatever calls it doesn't have to hang around for a response. I just passed an empty array for the response argument of $server->register. I thought that might achieve what I was looking for, but that's not been the case (client hangs around for a response).

The WSDL looks like this:

```
<message name="testfunctionRequest">
    <part name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="testfunctionResponse"/>
```

Is there a way to achieve such functionality with nusoap? I'm not sure if "fire and forget" is the right terminology to be using, so I've had a bit of trouble searching for possible answers to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detach current execution from web server process and close connection: using [pcntl_fork()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or running PHP script in background - [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Another option is to add information about request to some queue. This queue may be MySQL (or other DBMS) table or some kind of storage like [MemcacheQ](http://memcachedb.org/memcacheq/), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) etc. And, then, retrieve information from queue by another independent script and process it.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Ended up queuing the stuff in mysql, at least for the moment.