# Best way of using PHP to run a python script that needs to stay running?

Tags: php, python, shell

I have a web crawling script I'd like to initiate from a PHP page. It needs to run in the background and be able to be stopped from the page as well. What's the best way of accomplishing this? I know I can run shell line commands from PHP, but it seems like they would not be suitable for something that needs to keep running?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `exec()` in combination with bash's `&` like this:

```
<?php
exec('myscript.py &');
```

The `&` causes the process to run in the background.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Possible duplicate:

[Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Comment: Hi i'm trying to use: <?php
`exec('python3 /var/www/html/test.py > /var/www/html/log/out.txt 2> /var/www$` but it doesn't seem to be working. None of the output is being written to the files and I can't see it with `jobs`

Comment: Just had to chmod my logs directory - quick question, seems like its running but I'm not sure how to stop it?