# Asynchronously calling a Command in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to asynchronously call a Command from within a Controller in Symfony2.

So far i found the following solution:

```
$cmd = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/console '.(new MLCJobWorkerCommand)->getName().' '.$job->getId().' 2>&1 > /dev/null';
$process = new Process($cmd);
$process->start();
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

I need the Process to run in background and the Controller to return right after it started the former. I tried:

```
$cmd = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/console '
     .(new MLCJobWorkerCommand)->getName()
     .' '.$job->getId().' 2>&1 > /dev/null & echo \$!';
$process = new Process($cmd);
$process->mustRun();
$params["processid"] = $process->getOutput();
```

but the Controller doesn't return a Response until the Process has finished.

Comment: The problem is that the new process will stop as soon as the parent process is stopped as well, which is a limitation in PHP. A better solution might be to use a queueing system like RabbitMQ.

Comment: This looks great, I shall give it a try. In the past I used to start a background process in PHP in the manner indicated by my edit but the Controller seems to block here. Is this related to your comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Gerry that if you want to be "asynchronously" then you selected not the best way

I can recommend an alternative of RabbitMQ: JMSJobBundle
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation

Where you can create a queue of you console commands something like:

```
class HomeController ... {
    // inject service here
    private $cronJobHelper;
    // inject EM here
    private $em;

    public function indexAction() {
        $job = $this->cronJobHelper->createConsoleJob('myapp:my-command-name', $event->getId(), 10);
        $this->em->persist($job);
        $this->em->persist($job);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}


use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Entity\Job;

class CronJobHelper{

    public function createConsoleJob($consoleFunction, $params, $delayToRunInSeconds, $priority = Job::PRIORITY_DEFAULT, $queue = Job::DEFAULT_QUEUE){
        if(!is_array($params)){
            $params = [$params];
        }

        $job = new Job($consoleFunction, $params, 1, $queue, $priority);
        $date = $job->getExecuteAfter();
        $date = new \DateTime('now');
        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC')); //just in case
        $date->add(new \DateInterval('PT'.$delayToRunInSeconds.'S')); 
        $job->setExecuteAfter($date);

        return $job;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, JMSJobBundle seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [AsyncServiceCallBundle](https://github.com/krlove/async-service-call-bundle), it allows you to call your service's methods completely asynchronously using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222445/1667170) approach. The process responsible for current request handling doesn't wait for its child to be finished.

Everything you need is to call it like this:

```
$pid = $this->get('krlove.async')->call('service_id', 'method', [$argument1, $argument2]);
```