# Symfony Background Process FFmpeg video converting

Tags: php, symfony, ffmpeg, symfony-process

I am trying to convert a video with FFmpeg and everything works fine, but now I'm trying to do the converting process in the background, so I don't have to wait for the process to be done in a minute or so.

Is there any suggestion in how I can do this?

This is my current code in the controller:

```
$urlGenerator = new urlGenerator();
$user = $this->getUser ();
$userid = $user->getid ();
$username = $user->getFullname ();
$emailcomment = $this->container->getParameter ( 'mailer_sender_address' );

$ffmpeg = $this->get ( 'dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg' );
$ffprobe = $this->get ( 'dubture_ffmpeg.ffprobe' );

$currentDateTime = date ( 'YmdHis' );
$upload = new UploadVideo();

$em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
$form = $this->createForm ( new UploadVideoType(), $upload );
$userids = $em->getReference ( 'HotelPlanBundle\Entity\User', $userid );
$form->handleRequest ( $request );

if ( $form->isValid () || TRUE ) {
    $upload->upload ($userid);

    // Start transcoding and save video
    $upload->setUserid ( $userids );
    $upload->setTitle ( 'No title' );
    $upload->setCreatedDate ( new \DateTime() );

    $duration = $ffprobe
        ->format ( $upload->getWebPath () )// extracts file informations
        ->get ( 'duration' );

    $video = $ffmpeg->open ( $upload->getWebPath () );
    $video
        ->frame ( TimeCode::fromSeconds ( 10 ) )
        ->save ( __DIR__ . '/../../../web/uploads/documents/' . $currentDateTime . '.png' );

    $upload->setThumbnail ( $currentDateTime . '.png' );

    //here is where the converting takes too long !!
    $video->save ( new X264(), __DIR__ . '/../../../web/uploads/documents/' . $currentDateTime . '.mp4' );

    $upload->setVideoPath ( $currentDateTime . '.mp4' );
    $upload->setLink ( $urlGenerator->generateUrl () );
    $upload->setResetLink ( $urlGenerator->generateUrl () );

    try {
        $em->persist ( $upload );
        $em->flush ();
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        if ( $e->getPrevious ()->getCode () == '23000' ) {
            $upload->setLink ( $urlGenerator->generateUrl () );
            $em->persist ( $upload );
            $em->flush ();
    }
}
$em->persist ( $upload );
$em->flush ();

return new JsonResponse( array (
    'message' => 'Sucessfully Uploaded',
    'last_id' => $upload->getId ()
), 200 );
}
```

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should to move ffmpeg logic from the controller to a service.
flush your "upload" with new "unconverted" flag.

New service should get "upload" entity by passed id (that was generated after flush)

Then you should to create a console command that will get that service and call "convert" public method with passed id as param.

The service will make same ffmpeg logic that you have in the controller + update "unconverted" flag (ofc if you need to track this state)

Your controller should call new console command in background, for details you can see my suggestion in this answer [Asynchronously calling a Command in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601140/asynchronously-calling-a-command-in-symfony2)