# Many async shell_exec can cause performance problem in server?

Tags: php, web-services, asynchronous, shell-exec

During execution of a php webservice, i need to detach a "time consuming function" to maintain a quick response to the user. That's an example of the flow :

[image]

I know that php does not manage multi-thread operation by itself, but anyway there are some other methods to works in async way.
Googling and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php) on stackoverflow i have found a possible solution in the `shell_exec` command.

i have create this example to simulate the flow:

**service.php**

```
$urlfile=dirname(__FILE__)."/timefile.php";
$cmd = 'nohup nice -n 10 php -f '.$urlfile.' > log/file.log & printf "%u" $!';
$pid = shell_exec($cmd);

echo $pid;
```

**timefile.php**

```
 sleep(10);
 $urlfile=dirname(__FILE__)."/logfile.txt";
 $myfile = fopen($urlfile, "a");
 $txt = time()."\n";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
```

The code is only an example ( it writes into a txt file ) and it works asynchronous.

The flow will be upload on a Centos server with php and mysql installed. In real life *timefile.php* will execute from 3 to 6 curl call, i can estimate an execution time (for the entire file) of 30 seconds. *Timefile.php* will not act as a daemon, it will executed without only one time when it is called, so it will not remain open with a infinite *while loop* for instance.

Obviously the performance will depends on the server details, but my question is a little bit different. The webservice ( i hope ) will be call many times ( i can estimate 1000 times each hour ) and maybe there will be also concurrency troubles.

My code works as expected ,so my question is :

Using this approach ( with shell_exec as the example shows ) i will have performance trouble in server caused by the high number of detached process opened ?

Comment: also, consider using a ready made queue processing service such as Rabbit MQ

Comment: A simple calculation could be: A 1000 calls that take 30 seconds in total use 30.000 seconds. Since there are only 3600 seconds in a hour you will be, on average, running just over 8 of these `timefile.php` scripts at the same time. Add some randomness to that, and say a peak would be triple that number. It is quite easy to simulate this situation on your server, and you will have your answer.