# Interprocess communication within PHP with a continuous process?

Tags: php

I have a question about interprocess communication within PHP. What I want is to have one process to be continuously running, and to have other processes communicate with this one.Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

A very useful and popular interprocess communication mechanism is known as [Sockets](https://www.php.net/sockets).  PHP's support for it is just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I can also recommend Sockets, but using the [stream functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) like stream_socket_server() etc.

Because these are more programmer-friendly than the "raw" socket functions

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).  I have not used it extensively, but you should be able to accomplish this using this function.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly your needs are, you might wanna take a look at something lile [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)