# Interact with a C++ application throught CakePHP

Tags: c++, cakephp, architecture, cakephp-2.0

I'm wondering Which solution could be the best to interact with a C++ application and its data  through CakePHP over a Windows environment.

I was thinking about creating an API, with Delphi or Java for example, which could work with JSON requests and which at the same time would be linked to the C++ application.

This is a very generic question but I would like to have any feedback about this or know if anyone have tried something similar before and what solution was implemented for it.

Thanks.

Comment: can you modify the C++ application? If not, what interface does it provide?

Comment: Yeah, I could have full control over any of the layers. But the C++ application is the core and the less changes I would need to do there, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define "best": Most performant, easiest to implement, best scalable, most portable...?

If you can modify the C++ application, I would not create a component in the middle (what you suggest to write in Delphi or Java) but instead add an interface which PHP can access directly. If you cannot do this then you need to create such a component, of course. In this case, roughly the same options exist as for embedding the interface in the C++ app:

A simple approach is to use sockets (see [Interprocess communication within PHP with a continuous process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956245/interprocess-communication-within-php-with-a-continous-process)). A more heavyweight approach is http://activemq.apache.org/.

And of course you can expose a webservice (SOAP, REST, XML or JSON...). This is certainly a very portable interface but probably not the fastest (more layers in between).