# What technolgies and protocols would one use to allow a c program to start and interact with a web server?

Tags: html, c, linux, web-services

Here is a simplifed example.

I have a c program that runs as a daemon on an embedded linux system. For example we will say the program is a calculator that just does addition.

When someone starts the program, I would like a web server to be launched on the system that allows people to remotely use the calculator. The webserver will just serve a simple html page with 1 button "solve" and two input boxes. When someone clicks solve the numbers in the text box need to be sent to the c program, and then the solution needs to be sent back to the web server and displayed on the website.

I hope this isn't overly broad, but I'm just looking for what technologies would be used to accomplish this and a brief overview of how they interact, and hopefully I can take it from there and start digging in.

Comment: You mean like a CGI program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to start an external web server. Since your app is a deamon, you could use some HTTP server library inside your application -i.e. have an [embedded HTTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_HTTP_server) thru that library, e.g. D.Moreno's [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), GNU [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/), [EHS](http://ehs.fritz-elfert.de/), [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) etc..

If you already have an external web server, you could configure it to proxy your internal application web service, or make your application a [FastCgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) (or maybe `SCGI`) server.

PS. You need to be familiar with HTML5, [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP), [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request of HTTP, ...

Comment: Thank you these links are just what I was looking for. I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 0):

As the interaction is taken place between processes, I think you need interprocess communication mechanism here. However, you may not allowed to change the code of webserver. Here's some thing may help you:

- Use database ([mysql](http://www.mysql.com/)) which you can use sql to insert/fetch data both sides.
- If you use Php or someother script language, try [Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956245/interprocess-communication-within-php-with-a-continous-process)

Comment: For an embedded system that might be too heavyweight....