# How do I run a loop with a variable number of iterations in constant time?

Tags: php, arrays, random, time-complexity

Here I am rephrasing the question. Coz some of the people couldnt understand it and started giving negative votes

I have the following PHP code:

```
$count = 100000;
$array = array();
for($i=0,$i<=$count,$i++)
{
    array_push($array,mt_rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999));
}
```

As per current code the time to execute this code will increase as I increase `$count`.

I am looking for a solution / algo / technique by which I can keep the time to execute in seconds no matter whatever is the value for $count. I am running this on 8 cores cpu, I am OK changing language but not ok upgrading hardware.

Comment: Whatever the solution, if you need more elements in *array*, that will take more time - unless you can avoid using an array, meaning changing your algorithm/implementation?

Comment: You want to be able to execute an arbitrary function a million times and have it complete in the same time as just one? That's certainly daft and possibly nuts.

Comment: doesn't exist (to my knowledge), no matter what you have to iterate so...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for something impossible.

Comment: Thanks for quick comments

@ring0 can you suggest some algos.

Comment: Can I run it as a threaded process? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532065/php-multithread

Comment: Could you explain why you think you need to do this? I think you are asking the wrong question here.

Comment: @vascowhite I want to generate large sets of random numbers and insert it into DB

Comment: why do u guys think this question is off topic
it is a question which involves 
*a software algorithm

*practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

Answer (score 2):

This should give you approximately constant time for values of $count < $maxcount. However, I wouldn't ever do this - it is just timewasting.

```
$maxcount = 100000
$count = 100000;
$array = array();

// Create required array
for($i=0,$i<=$count,$i++)
{
    array_push($array,mt_rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999));
}

// Pad out time to $maxcount iterations, to keep time constant
for($i=$count,$i<=$maxcount,$i++)
{
    $dummy = mt_rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999);
}
```

Comment: This is resolved using pthreads in php and a small Java code. Thanks for all your comments.