# Running multiple functions in php

Tags: php, process

I need to run several functions at the same time. I had successfully implemented in C# by creating an ElapsedEventHandler and executing it when a timer gets elapsed. In this way I could run a number of functions at the same time (delegates). How can I do the same thing using php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

PHP supports multitasking now. See the [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) API.

---

PHP does not have multi-threading. So you'd have to spawn another php process through CLI and run that script.

checkout these questions for more info:

- [how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)
- [does-php-have-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)

Comment: this is based on the assumption that you want to run the functions at the same time (simultaneouesly).

Comment: Which is a fair assumption since the question explicitly says that.

Comment: so you are saying that PHP does not have multi-threading and link to an answer where it says with a font of 30 that Multi-threading is possible in php.

Comment: @Claudiu - I answered this in 2009. The link I've added points to the question and not the answer. This [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads) shows all releases of the pthreads package that provides multithreading support with the earliest alpha release coming out in 2012. Sorry, I couldn't spare the time to go back and revise all my answers all the time as new developments happen, but you're most welcome to down vote this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function foo() {
  echo "foo\n";
}

function bar() {
  echo "bar\n";
}

class multifunc {
 public $functions = array();
 function execute() {
  foreach ($this->functions as $function) $function();
 }
}

$test = new multifunc();
$test->functions[] = 'foo';
$test->functions[] = 'bar';
$test->execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

just create an array where you put all the functions you wanna run, then loop the array and run the functions.

```
foreach($functions as $func)
{
    $func();
}
```

is that what you wanna do?

Comment: Oh God.. You can do that? Wow! I will try it out and come back to you.

Comment: I have suddenly realised that this wont be possible since in my code a function has to sleep, letting the other function to execute..

Comment: This runs the functions sequentially, not at the same time.

Answer (score -3):

This is how you can imitate that:

```
   function runFuncs()
   {
     function1(); // run funciton1
     function2(); // run funciton2
     function3(); // run funciton3
     function4(); // run funciton4
     function5(); // run funciton5
   }
```

When you run **runFuncs()**; it runs all functions inside it.

Comment: I cant do that, bcoz I dont know initially what functions will run. That will depend on the user. When I did created the same program in C# I used the following code:
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(function_name);
by this I could add any function sort of dynamically...

Comment: I believe he means the timer stuff.

Comment: @Sahil: You can use `register_tick_function()` and check for the right timestamp to execute.