# Threads in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, zend-framework

I am creating a web application using zend, here I create an interface from where user-A can send email to more than one user(s) & it works excellent but it slow the execution time because of which user-A wait too much for the "acknowledged response" ( which will show after the emails have sent. )

In Java there are "Threads" by which we can perform that task (send emails) & it does not slow the rest application.

Is there any technique in PHP/Zend just like in Java by which we can divide our tasks which could take much time eg: sending emails.

Comment: Are you using a `Transport`? See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.multiple-emails.html

Comment: There is a detailed answer for this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading/14201579#14201579

Answer (score 41, accepted):

EDIT (thanks @Efazati, there seems to be new development in this direction)

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php
Caution: (from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) on the bottom):

> pthreads was, and is, an experiment with pretty good results. Any of its limitations or features may change at any time; [...]

/EDIT

No threads in PHP!

The *workaround* is to store jobs in a queue (say rows in a table with the emails) and have a cronjob call your php script at a given interval (say 2 minutes) and poll for jobs. When jobs present fetch a few (depending on your php's install timeout) and send emails.

The main idea to defer execution:

- main script adds jobs in the queue
- cron script sends them in tiny slices

Gotchas:

- make sure u don't send an email without deleting from queue (worst case would be if a user rescieves some spam at 2 mins interval ...)
- make sure you don't delete a job without executing it first ...
- handle bouncing email using a score algorithm

Comment: +1. This is how most mailing list systems work that are using PHP.

Comment: Some people create libs named Thread.php based on pcntl claiming to "emulate" threads, and a lot of [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) comes out of this unfortunate naming ... /cc downvoters

Comment: what about this? PHP: Thread - Manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: This isn't true ^_^ -- you don't need cron to multithread. But it depends on your environment. Shared hosting will probably not give you the access you need to popen your helper threads.

Answer (score 5):

You could look into using multiple processes, such as with [fork](http://php.net/function.pcntl-fork).  The communication between them wouldn't be as simple as with threads (but then, it won't come with all of its pitfalls either), but if you're just sending emails, it might not be necessary to communicate much, if at all.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for doing forks on an Apache process.  You may get some behaviors that you are not expecting.  If you are looking to do any kind of asynchronous execution it should be via some kind of queuing mechanism.  Gearman is one.  Zend Server Job Queue is another.  I have some demo code at [Do you queue? Introduction to the Zend Server Job Queue](http://www.eschrade.com/page/queue-introduction-zend-server-queue-4b8eef5c).  Cron can be used, but you'll have the problem of depending on your cron scheduler to run tasks whereas asynchronous computing often needs to be run immediately.  Using a queuing system allows you to do that without threading.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Threading extension being developed based on PThreads that looks promising at https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Answer (score 1):

There is [pcntl](http://php.net/manual/intro.pcntl.php), which allows you to create sub-processes, but php doesn't work very well for this kind of architecture. You're probably better off creating a long-running script (a daemon) and spawning multiple of them.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP there are no threads in it. However for php, you can have a look at this roundabout way
http://www.alternateinterior.com/2007/05/multi-threading-strategies-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a queue system for your email sending and send the email from another system which supports threads. PHP is just a tool and you should the tool that is best fitted for the job.

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't include threading as part of the language, there are some methods that can emulate it but they aren't foolproof.

[This Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=GGV&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=php+threading&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) shows a few potential workarounds