# scan a string and replace tags with links

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have an array like this:

```
$keywords = array( 'php', 'html', 'css' );
```

I have a db query to return a paragraph, which contains the keywords previously mentioned in the array.

I have a link template like this:

```
$linktpl = '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>';
```

I want a simple function to scan that paragraph and on the fly, whenever it finds a keyword it converts it to a link using the link template above.

And if possible I want it to take into account singular and plural (like framework and frameworks)

and is it safe for SEO to make this automated keyword linking?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = 'this is the php test subject.';

// associate keywords with their urls
$urls = array(
'php' => 'http://www.php.net',
// and etc...
);

// this callback will take the matches from preg and generate the
// html link making use of the $urls dictionary
$linker = function($matches) use($urls) {
    $urlKey = strtolower($matches[1]);
    return sprintf(
      '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
      $urls[$urlKey], $matches[1], $matches[1]
    );
};

// do the magic
$regex = '/\b(' . preg_quote(implode('|', $keywords), '/') . ')\b/i';
preg_replace_callback($regex, $linker, $string);
```

Advantage of using regular expressions is that we can leverage the `\b` modifier to ensure we catch cases such as `(php)`, `PHP.`, or `phpp` and deal with them properly.

Answer (score 2):

This will work but isn't necessarily the best way.  It joins your array with pipe characters, and uses that string to build a regex.  `preg_replace()` then does the rest.  Requires that you change your link template to use the `preg_replace()` style instead of the `printf()` style

```
preg_replace("/\b(" . implode("|", $keywords) .")\b/", "<a href='\\1'>\\1</a>", $paragraph);
```

**EDIT**: added `\b` word boundaries so you only match whole words and not inner substrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$paragraph = /* YOUR PARAGRAPH CONTENT */;
$paragraph = str_replace( array( 'php' , 'html' , 'css' ) , array( '<a href="url/php/" title="php">PHP</a>' , '<a href="url/html/" title="html">HTML</a>' , '<a href="url/css/" title="css">CSS</a>' ) , $paragraph );
```

Answer (score 1):

First up, this can be way more complicated then it seems. Namely, this will replace words that are inside of a word, IE if we had `script`  the term `javascript` would be half link, half word. I dunno if you care. One way to fix it, would be to add spaces before and after the word. But again, this as it's issues, as what about punctuations? (.,!?) etc.

Depending on your needs you may need to do some regex and complicate it up. There is also the note that you could be creating links within links, if your text can contain links.

Just some items to think about. I think there are quite a few examples of this on SO already so it may be worth to search this site to see what you can find. Given the over complexity, I am not able to provide that code. If you just need the simple method, the others who have posted, should work just fine.

---

Some references:

[Replacing keywords in text with php & mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636295/replacing-keywords-in-text-with-php-mysql/2636460#2636460)

Answer (score 1):

For your main question, one of the above 3 answers should suffice.

Regarding this question :

```
and is it safe for SEO to make this automated keyword linking?
```

It is safe enough..

But there are some concerns which need be addressed

1. Check page 13 in this [SEO Guide by
   Google](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aY548b63XmtgJ%3awww.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf%20google%20seo%20guide&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgpbA5gASwUBSlBKQaEt2DpJ8JVwirPUz1meklw8IHKhG2kQF4g2GZQdRoFIOFY0roQwz3lfkIyG321sxRbVDk4fvyY_3xZrlGf_Hcb1gf_a43exe7GCW8JGjx3h3oNNHDYUR3p&sig=AHIEtbTp6K4JxFjWWSBEBmeuF4QWdYuT-w). So, it is always better
   to have good anchor text. I assume
   through this method you won't get a
   very proper one.
2. As Brad explained, don't overdo it.
   Hence , may be have only 2-3
   keywords per page, 1 link per
   keyword in a paragraph and a total
   of 6-7 links in a page. You need to
   be careful in not having lot of
   links.
3. "The title attribute specifies extra
   information about an element." So
   dumping just a keyword over there
   may not help.

It is always better to go for manual methods rather than automation for SEO'ing your stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @med What hey means is that you shouldn't over do it and actually manually add the keywords linked to it that are relative to the text. This ensures that they are properly done and not over done, IE a link farm type setup.

Comment: over doing it is clear, but what about links that are relative to the text? for example ( <a href="mysite.com/php/" title="php">php</a> ) would this be a problem?

Comment: @med, As long as they are relative I really do not see a problem. But you may consider just linking the first keyword and not all the `php` keywords in the text, so it is not "overdone".

Comment: ok thanks man ;) I think about doing it manually but will it be a good practice to write full anchor tags in the database? or maybe I have to put the keywords I want between two special characters and then do one of those scripts to process only those keywords instead of an array?

Comment: @med What I wanted to say was that you need to optimize your anchor text. I updated the post to make it clear. Also what Brad said is a point to consider. Adding to that, "title" attribute is designed to give description. So just dumping keyword there might even give adverse effects

Comment: so what is better for SEO? to remove the title tag or to keep it and make it a little different?

Comment: @med Try to make it descriptive. depends on the keyword. Also, most modern search engines don't give heavy importance to it.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` will almost definitely be the fastest way of performing the search/replace

I'd suggest you first build you array of search words, then the replacements and then perform the replace.

```
$searches = array("php", "html", "css");
$replacements = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) {
    $replacements[] = sprintf($linktmpl, $row['url'], $row['title'], $row['word']);
}
$html = str_replace($searches, $replacements, $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

> and is it safe for SEO to make this automated keyword linking?

Depends on how you make use of it. If it's too obvious and search engines see a pattern you might wake up one day and find your sites banned from SERPS.