# PHP How to replace html tags with values

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, dynamic

I have thousands of static HTML lines in a text file and I want to keep the "H-number" value that is between a specific HTML tag called "num" and turn it into a link by using PHP. For example, the HTML strings look like this:

`</tvm><br><num>H7585</num></td><td><font color="#663399">...`

From this I want to get the part `<num>H7585</num>` and turn it into something like this keeping the "H-number" value:

`</tvm><br><a href="https://link-here.php?id=H7585"><num>H7585</num></a></td><td><font color="#663399">...`

However, all the "H-number" codes like `H7585` are different, and they are not inside a PHP variable since everything is a string of HTML text. I have tried the PHP functions preg_match and preg_replace but I can't come up with a solution.

Something I have tried is this. But I don't know how to get the different H-number values to show or display:

`$string = '...</tvm><br><num>H7585</num></td><td><font color="#663399">......</tvm><br><num>H72000</num></td><td><font color="#663399">......</tvm><br><num>H8525</num></td><td><font color="#663399">...';` - (there are thousands of lines like this though, with different H-number codes).

`$string = preg_replace("/<num>(.+?)<\\/num>/is", "<a href=display_value_here><num>display_value_here</num></a>", $string);`

`$echo $string;`

Would anyone please help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scan a string and replace tags with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889873/scan-a-string-and-replace-tags-with-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [DOMDocument API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), by creating a document, loading your HTML into it, looking for desired nodes using [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) then replacing them with the newly created link elements:

```
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML(utf8_decode($markup), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);
$domDocument->encoding = 'utf-8';

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);

/** @var DOMElement $numElement */
foreach ($xpath->query('//num') as $numElement) {
  $linkElement = $domDocument->createElement('a');
  $linkElement->setAttribute('href', "https://link-here.php?id={$numElement->textContent}");
  $numElement->parentNode->replaceChild($linkElement, $numElement);
  $linkElement->appendChild($numElement);
}

$newMarkup = $domDocument->saveHTML();
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/XJ8Zi**

Note: using regular expressions is not recommended to parse XML/HTML.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The code works perfectly and it is what I needed. I want to thank you for taking the time to help me. Keep up the great work!

Comment: I have a question. What can I change in the code so that the output keeps intact the words with special accents or characters?

Comment: @Arlo Check with the updated code (I didn't update the demo link, just the code in the answer).

Comment: The update works awesome! All the utf-8 characters now display the accents. The code works great! I really appreciate it. If the string also includes greek letters and other accents like Azōr or Ἀζὼρ what could be a different option instead of utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '</tvm><br><num>H7585</num></td><td><font color="#663399">......</tvm><br><num>H72000</num></td><td><font color="#663399">......</tvm><br><num>H8525</num></td><td><font color="#663399">';
$res = preg_replace('/<num>(.+?)<\/num>/i','<a href="$1"><num>$1<\/num><\/a>', $str);
var_dump($res);
```

There was `\` extra in your match regex. Also you can use `$1` to represent your captured values.